# Arguments to system call

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to write a simple shell in c, i started off by snatching some code from the net for the simple parsing but I'm having an issue, when i try to execute commands with args, for example ls -l it will just ignore the argument, does system() not take in consideration these arguments? Code below anyway

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define DELIMS " \t\r\n"
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *cmd;
  char line[1024];
  printf("Starting Omar's Shell\n");
  while (1) {
    printf("What can i do for you?>");

    if (!fgets(line, 1024, stdin)) break;
    // Parse and execute command
    if (cmd = strtok(line, DELIMS)) {
      // Clear errors
      errno = 0;

      if (strcmp(cmd, "exit") == 0) {
        break;

      } else {
          if(system(line) !=0){
          printf("An error has occured\n");
          }
      }

      if (errno) perror("Command failed");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strtok` breaks original line. That's how it works, it inserts `'\0'` so you can iterate through tokens. Either use different approach or copy your string before using strtok.

Comment: I tried @CoolGuy but it didnt seem to work, so instead I copied the string right before I call strtok() and executed the command with the copy instead. Are there any other ways to deal with this ?

Comment: There are always other ways. You can implement non-breaking strtok alternative that will copy word to separate buffer instead of breaking original. Or if your shell is intended to be more or less advanced, it could be a good idea to implement lexical analyser and handle tokens extraction within it.

Answer (score 0):

`strtok` breaks original line. That's how it works, it inserts `'\0'` so you can iterate through tokens. Either use different approach or copy your string before using `strtok`. –  keltar